# combinations totaling to sum in 2d

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, permutation, partition

The task is to find all `N×N` matrices `M` with integer values, when the sums
along the cols and rows are fixed.

For `N=3` this means: Find the matrix `M`

```
m11 m12 m13
m21 m22 m23
m31 m32 m33
```

so that

```
m11 + m12 + m13 = r1
m21 + m22 + m23 = r2 
m31 + m32 + m33 = r3
```

and

```
m11 + m21 + m31 = c1
m12 + m22 + m32 = c2 
m13 + m23 + m33 = c3
```

holds.

e.g.: For

```
r1=3, r2=6, r3=9,
c1=5, c2=6, c3=7
```

one solution would be:

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
4 3 2
```

The only algorithm I came up is to calculate straightforward all possible partitions for the rows, start with the first partition (`p11`, `p12`, `...`, `p1N`) of the first column, select all compatible partitions (`p21`, `p22`, `...`, `p2N`) of the second row by checking `p11+p21 <= c1`, `...`, `p1N+p2N <= cN`, and proceed with the third row. If one wants to visit all possible solutions this scales obviously very badly with `N`.

The 1D problem - the partition of a number `A` into `N` parts - is solved by a number of algorithms. One basic idea is to calculate all possibilities to split a string of `A` '+' by `(N-1)` '|' and count the numbers of `+` between the `|` (e.g.: `+++|++|+|` yields `3,2,1,0`). I wonder if it is possible to extend this ansatz to the 2D problem. Also, I suspect that it might be possible to calculate a solution based on the preceding solution and iterate over all solutions.